# Web service generated XML unexpected token error on parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, web-services, parsing

I got a XML file from a web service and now I want to parse it in android, but it gives me *unexpected token* error; my XML is:

```
     Latest{LatestResult=<Root>
     <Version>1.0</Version>
    <ReportName>Latest</ReportName>
    <Reports>
     <Report>
       <Code>I</MarketCode>
       <Date>13930506</TradeDate>
       <Broker>666    </BrokerCode>

     </Report>
     <Report>
       <Code>J</MarketCode>
       <Date>13930506</TradeDate>
       <Broker>666    </BrokerCode>

     </Report>
     <Report>

     <Code>I</MarketCode>
       <Date>13930506</TradeDate>
       <Broker>666    </BrokerCode>
      </Report>
      </Reports>
```

I think the parser couldn't detect `{` and `=` in first line of XML.

Comment: It can't because that isn't valid XML.  Why is it in there?

Comment: it has a <Root> tag at the end of the xml...but i think that the error is in line 1....

Comment: this error will not occur for any reader which know what is XML!

Answer (score 2):

This string simply is not XML. Problems start in line 1 with some extra text:

```
Latest{LatestResult=<Root>
```

and continue a bit later with unmatched start and end tags:

```
   <Code>J</MarketCode>
   <Date>13930506</TradeDate>
   <Broker>666    </BrokerCode>
```